# How to get rid of space between an image and caption?

Tags: html

[This is a picture of the spacing problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZGe0.png)

On my website, I have a image and its caption, but there is a big space between the image and caption. I don't know what is causing this, because there are no br tags. What should I do? I like to use html.

```
<p style="float: right; width:300px; vertical-align: top;"><font size="4">Members of FBLA reciving an award for their competitions. (From biznews.fiu.edu). To learn more about middle level competitions from FBLA's national website, click <a href="http://www.fbla-pbl.org/middle-level/competitive-recognition/" target="blank">here.</a></font></p>
```

Comment: how can we get with one line?

Answer (score 0):

You should give us more details about your page html / css code.

Have you tried to change the `margin-top` of your caption or the `margin-bottom` of your image?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you have some margin either on image block or tag p. By the way, if you have float: right, you don't need vertical-align-top.